# Rails log cookie information if ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionpack

I am raising a `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow` error.

In theory I know why this is happening, my session data is over 4k.

However I dont know what in my session would make it over 4k.

The stack trace of the error is as follows:

`raise CookieOverflow if options[:value].size > MAX_COOKIE_SIZE`

Is it possible to override `ActionPack` and log `options[:value]`

Also it is not an option to store sessions in the database as the database would grow too fast.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up forking ActionPack and monkey patching it to raise and error with the cookie